# Deploy app with publish_actions permission to live

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created app which uses publish_actions permissions on facebook and test app for it. Added sharing feature on test site and sent application for review. Facebook approved it. But now I slill can share only from test accounts. I understand that it is probably because of it's test app, but I'm affraid that this feature won't work when I deploy it to live serer.
Also since facebook approved my application it's changed a little bit (added new feature which also uses publish_actions). Is it ok? Or do I need send request again?

Comment: You need to submit your actual app for review - you can not substitute the test app for it for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. But if I add changes to my live site - it won't work until facebook approve my request, but all users who use my site will see that functionality for sharing exists but they won't be able to use it. This is what worries me the most.

Comment: Then provide a test environment under a subdomain.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get. Could you please explain what I should do?

Comment: The live version of the app is available under `http://example.com/`, so you set up `http://staging.example.com/` or something similar, and have your new code running there, on that subdomain.

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot. That is a goo advice. So such url - http://staging.example.com/ - if I add something to live url still will be as a live site for Facebook?

Comment: And there isn't any other way?